# Get weird Output like "Values@7d5b6e" instead of some certain strings

Tags: java, xml, object, guava

I got my objects of called Values, it looks like this:

```
class Values{
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String value;

public Values(String name, String type, String value)
    {this.name = name; this.type = type; this.value = value;}
public String getName()
    {return name;}
public String getType()
    {return type;}
public String getValue()
   {return value;}
  }
```

My Datamodel looks like this. MY Input is a XML-File. A package contains some classes and every class got Attributes with a name, a type and a value. The class Values above should represent one attribute.

I use Multimaps to save this information. The desired output is like this, for example.

```
[PackageName:[ObjectName1, Values1],
             [ObjectName1, Values2],
             [ObjectName2, Values1]]
```

My code to process the input XML-File is like this. The For-loops are to iterate through the datastructure of the input file.

```
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        org.jdom2.Document doc = builder.build(input);
        Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
        List<Element> listPackages = rootNode.getChildren();


        for(Element packages : listPackages)
        {   
                List<Element> objectInstanceList = packages.getChildren();

                for(Element objects : objectInstanceList) 
                {
                    Map<String, Multimap<String,Values>> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, Multimap<String, Values>>();

                    List<Element> listObjectClasses = objects.getChildren();
                    bdbID = objects.getName();
                    if (objects.getAttributes().size() == 0)
                    {   
                    for(Element classes : listObjectClasses) 
                      {     
                    List<Element> listObjectAttributes = classes.getChildren();

                        for(Element objectAttributes : listObjectAttributes)
                        {

                            Multimap<String, Values> mm = HashMultimap.create();
                            String name = objectAttributes.getAttributeValue("name");
                            String type = objectAttributes.getAttributeValue("type");
                            String value = objectAttributes.getAttributeValue("value"); 
                            Values v = new Values(name, type, value);                   
                            mm.put(classes.getName(), v);
                                         System.out.println(name +":" + type + ":" + value);
                            System.out.println(v);
                        }
                        valuesMap.put(bdbID, mm);
                     }
                   }
             }
     }
```

The 2 prints at the end are for test purposes and here comes my question. Regading the output of both prints.

Output 1:

```
Bandwidth:KiloBitPerSecond:50   //Name:Type:Value
```

Output 2:

```
Dataprocessing.Values@7d5b6e   // Dataprocessing = Java-Package which contains the class.
```

The question is, why do I get this weird Output? Is it wrong to use a class like Values for this purpose? If somebody knows a better Idea to do this, I am open for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) representation of `Values`. You need to override `toString` in that class to provide formatted output

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Values [name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", value=" + value + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ovveride the `toString()`  method in your   `Values` class.

As per docs of toString()

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So

`Dataprocessing.Values@7d5b6e`  is the textual representation of Values class.

You just  ovveride  `toString` method in `Values`  class.

```
class Values {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String value;

    public Values(String name, String type, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
            public String toString() {
                 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                 result.append(this.name ).append(",");  
                 result.append(this.type ).append(",");
                 result.append(this.value )
                 return result.toString();
            }
}
```

Comment: thanks, works great, didnt thought about that. Reimus was faster, so I accepted his answer, but yours is as good aswell.

Comment: No issues,It helped. Glad :)